# How to change DatePickerDialog year text size?

Tags: android, themes

[DatePickerDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGP3q.png)

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#3f4d68</item>

</style>
```

how to change theme year Text Size?

Comment: HI new contributer! Please refer to the guidelines on how to post a question. You need to give more explanation on what you're trying to achieve with the help of screenshots or code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

set custom style in Style folder like as below:

```
<style name="CustomStyle_DatePicker" parent="Material.App.Dialog.DatePicker">
    <item name="dp_dayTextSize">15sp</item>

 </style>
```

then set the style in java class where you have set the datepicker

```
 builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(R.style.CustomStyle_DatePicker)
```

Comment: sorry, not to use Material theme.
use "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"